# php send mail functikon not working within a cron job set up with cPanel

Tags: php, email, cron

I have a cron job set up that includes the php email() function within it. When the cron job executes on the automatic schedule set in cPanel, no emails are sent.

I know that the cron script and its path are correct because 1) it executes correctly and sends email when I call it directly from my browser and 2) I am sent a notice of no errors by the Cron Daemon when it finishes. I also can use php include() other other scripts and update my database by cron so I know that the path is correct in the cron command line.

The command line for the cron job is:

/usr/bin/php -q /home/nblygsmt/public_html/Utilities/cronjobs/crontest3.php

I have stripped the script down to just the email lines to pinpoint the problem. It happens only in the send email function when called automatically as a cron job.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could be a user permissions issue; Is the cronjob running as the same user as the web-server? Or are you using an external smtp server and authenticating via your php script? And does your script run successfully from the command line? Also note that things like session variables are not set when running the script as a cron job.

Comment: Not sure on most of that. No session variables involved. It's all the same user.

Comment: You should at the very least post the code you are using to mail your message. I also doubt that it's all the same user, what operating system is the server on?

Comment: Not sure on most of that. No session variables involved. It's all the same user as far as I know. Don't know how to run it from a command line on the production server. When I run it from the browser through my WAMP local server it all works fine and emails are sent. I don't know what an external smtp server is - I am using the php email function on a commercial webhost that has Apache2.2.25,cpanel11.42.1, php5.3.27

Comment: Have you checked the return value of the `mail()` function? If that is `true`, the problem is not with the php.

Answer (score 0):

If the script is working when you call it directly you could use wget instead

```
wget http://example.com/Utilities/cronjobs/crontest3.php
```